# Does technology exist that could allow devices to access and use data without having to download or stream it?

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net

Say the data never has to be copied to the client device, but always remains locked in the server.  Say all the requesting device does is "hack in" to the server using a special code and only downloads some kind of tiny-size alias that gives it access to the entire file(s) on the server?  Does this technology already exist, or if not, does it sound possible?

Comment: It exists, consider Citrix / Remote Desktop, you do not stream download or stream the data, only the graphical representation of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It's called client-server architecture. You're using it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Data can be written (insert/update) without having to download it.  To suggest that data could be read without downloading it is a contradiction in terms.  Reading the data *is* downloading it.  You can read different views on the data (eg, charts, graphical representations, or aggregations) without downloading the entire data set, but this is still downloading the data that you are reading.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is similarly achieved with remote monitoring/controlling the server thorugh a client on the devices , but yet then you have to download the stream of pictures taken from the server and upload commands to it.

it would be less bandwidth but less quality too..

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs a bit more specificity, but basically, your application has to get the data *somehow*.  There are a variety of ways to accomplish that, not all of which involve downloading or "streaming" the data.  For example, the client could make, say, a request for some specific data, and the server could return it without having to return *all* the data.  (This sentence, of course, describes a database.)  Or, if you just want less network transit but do want the entire set of data on your device, compress it and send it.  You would need a compression algorithm that performs well enough.  Depending what you mean by "tiny-size alias," this may or may not suffice for you.